# To Check whether a date is between two dates in column in MongoDB using JAVA

Tags: java, web-services, mongodb

I am working on web-services by using java with MongoDB, in that i am trying to check whether a date time say "2015-04-16 16:32:49" lies between the date time present in the fields start_time and end_time from table.In mysql i tried the following query

> select * from tablename where Employee_id =101  and '2015-04-16
>   16:32:49' between start_time and end_time;

i am trying to replicate the same using java in MongoDB by using following code

```
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
            whereQuery.put("employeeID", "101");
            String date = "2015-04-17 11:02:49";
            whereQuery.put(date, new BasicDBObject("$gt", "start_time ")
                    .append("$lt", "end_time "));
DBCursor cursor = col.find(whereQuery);
```

but the code is not working, it is not comparing the date specified with the two column in table,what is the right syntax to do that

if i try this code

```
whereQuery.put(someOtherField, new BasicDBObject("$gt", "2015-04-17 11:02:49")
                        .append("$lt", "2015-04-19 11:02:49"));
```

it is working i need the syntax to compare a date String with two fields in entire table

Comment: What is the datatype of `"start_time"` and `end_time`?

Comment: `String date` is used to compare with `date` type field of MongoDB. What happens when you pass `java.sql.Date` ?

Comment: DATE datatype in MongoDB

Comment: But wherequery.put(String key,Object value) i have to send only String as a key and DBObject as value

Comment: That's the problem you are comparing string object with Date object. Can you show us your document?

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("552fb9b377c7ec0e7c1324d5"),
    "blockID" : "B",
    "floorID" : "6",
    "employeeName" : "xxx",
    "employeeID" : "13",
    "roomRange" : "7F,B1",
    "isActive" : 0,
    "updateDateTime" : ISODate("2015-04-16T13:31:31.765Z"),
    "start_time" : ISODate("2015-04-16T11:02:49.000Z"),
    "end_time" : ISODate("2015-04-16T11:02:49.000Z")
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query roughly translates to:

```
select * from tablename where Employee_id =101 and '2015-04-16 16:32:49' > "start_time" and '2015-04-16 16:32:49' < "end_time";
```

You are comparing string `"start_time"` and `"end_time"` with `'2015-04-16 16:32:49'`.

Correct query would be:-

```
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        whereQuery.put("employeeID", "101");
        String date_string = "2015-04-17 11:02:49";
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = format.parse(date_string);
        whereQuery.put("start_time", new BasicDBObject("$lt", date));
        whereQuery.put("end_time", new BasicDBObject("$gt", date));
DBCursor cursor = col.find(whereQuery);
```

You can use a regular JAVA date object.

Comment: Thanks i think it should work ,  this is the record have to fetch but it is not getting this {
    "_id" : ObjectId("552fba6577c7ec1f6c2ec830"),
    "blockID" : "B",
    "floorID" : "3",
    "employeeName" : "xxx",
    "employeeID" : "13",
    "roomRange" : "1,2,3",
    "isActive" : 0,
    "updateDateTime" : ISODate("2015-04-16T13:34:28.781Z"),
    "shiftStartTime" : ISODate("2015-04-16T11:02:49.000Z"),
    "shiftEndTime" : ISODate("2015-04-18T11:02:49.000Z")
}

Comment: If you are looking for an exact match you should use `$gte` and '$lte` instead of  `$gt` and `$lt`.

Comment: This is the mongo Query which is running but not getting the record    { "employeeID" : "13" , "isActive" : 0 , "shiftStartTime" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : "2015-01-17T05:32:49.000Z"}} , 
"shiftEndTime" : { "$lt" : { "$date" : "2015-01-17T05:32:49.000Z"}}}

Comment: As I said in the above comment use a combination of `$gte` and `$lte` to include time for which `shiftStartTime` and `shiftEndTime` are equal.

Comment: Yeah i understand but even the shiftStartTime and shiftEndTime is not equal they are 2015-04-16T11:02:49.000Z and 2015-04-18T11:02:49.000Z

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I got it confused with your query. In your query however you are using `$gt` for `shiftStartTime` , just interchange it with `$lt` in `shiftEndTime`.

Comment: No it is not getting the record cursor does not having any object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75495/discussion-between-thegreenogre-and-vicky).

Comment: I have found the error the SimpleDateFormat in the code is wrong, small mm for Month that why the record is not fetched after changed it to MM the record is fetching thanks for reply @thegreenogre